# Xamarin Forms - Android project getting error Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Can't make a decor toolbar out of NULL Object'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I am working on a very old Xamarin project(XF 2.4) and now I have updated it into the latest xamarin version and updated the rest of the things into the latest tool. Everything is resolved except a single thing, My toolbar(navigation bar) is not visible but app working fine.

This is my original code(before the update) in MainActivity of android project

```
[Activity(Label = "Town Manager", Icon = "@drawable/andoid_appIcon",
   Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity {
```

After update XF, the navigation bar(toolbar) was hidden in the UI in all the pages. then I read on internet and follow an article which is Adding AppCompat and Material Design to the old project. It uses FormsAppCompatActivity instead of FormsApplicationActivity. here is the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/appcompat-material-design

I have added Toolbar.xml, style.xml, and the rest of the things as new XF project format required.
now mainactivity code look like this

```
[Activity(Label = "Town Manager", Icon = "@drawable/andoid_appIcon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
```

But application getting a crash when calling the DisplayAlert() or pickers. Error is **Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Can't make a decor toolbar out of NULL Object'**
[image]
[image]

I tried to resolve this issue, whole the day but always app getting crash when it call any where DisplayAlert.
Any idea, experience regarding this ?

Comment: I tested the `DisplayAlert` function with the newest Xamarin.Forms, it works fine.Please mark sure the Xamarin.Forms package is also updated on the Android platform. Try to update the nuget packages of the Droid project to the lastest statable version. If the project is not very heavy, you could try to create a new project with the new version packages. Then copy the sample code to the project.

Comment: yes, all projects has updated with latest XF.

Comment: Have you update the nuget packages in xamarin android project ?